# how to use yacc in the other file

Tags: c++, yacc

I want to use [yacc](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/yacc-yet-another-compiler-compiler) as a compiler in my project. But I don't know whether it is possible to call `yyparse()` in the other function, so that I don't need to set main function in the file `*.y`.

Hoping someone could tell me the function or the implement, Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it? If so and you encountered some unexpected result, ask a more soecific question.

Comment: As @rici said your question is not very clear.  It sounds like you are asking if you can call yyparse() from an arbitrary function or location.  The answer to that is yes yyparse() can be called from where ever you need to start the parsing operation.  If that wasn't what you were asking then please clarify.

Comment: Okay, in fact , I want to know how to calling the function defined in the *.y file. I need a implement that I could use to call yylex